# jQuery .text() does not appear in html, but in console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of code

```
$('.bartext').text(percentComplete + "%");
```

In the `html` it renders like

```
<p class="bartext text" style="font-size: 14.020371290794092px;"></p>
```

But the `console.log` of

```
console.log($('.bartext').text(percentComplete + "%"));
```

says

```
[p.bartext text, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: ".bartext", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]
```

With `outerHTML` of

```
"<p class="bartext text" style="font-size: 14.020371290794092px;">100%</p>"
```

And `outerText` of

```
"100%"
```

**EDIT:** The whole part

```
$.ajax({
            xhr: function()
            {
                var XHR = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                XHR.addEventListener('progress', function(evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
                        console.log(percentComplete);
                        $('.bar').css('width', (percentComplete * 2));
                        $('.bartext').text(percentComplete + "%");
                    }
                }, false);
                return XHR;
            },
            type: 'GET',
            url: page, 
            data: {ajax : 1},
            success: function(data) {
            $('.content').empty().append(data);
            }
        });
```

What is going on?
Thank you!!!
:D

Comment: Do you use a *Document ready function*? And what on earth should be `14.020371290794092px`

Comment: try doing with $('.bartext.text').text(percentComplete + "%"));

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan This whole part is in an `xhr` object of an `ajax` request. But the corresponding line before to update the progress bar works fine!!! The crumpy `px` comes from my little text resize function. See it live here http://liebdich.biz/blanc. On `window.resize`. ;)

Comment: @BharathRallapalli Does not work. :)

Comment: @BharathRallapalli Why **should** that work?

Comment: @dollarvar probably you're returning the Function Object instead of a Number or String.

Comment: @still_learning I thought there are more elements with bartext so , gave a shot .. :)

Comment: @dollarvar check this once http://jsfiddle.net/D3PnX/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Could you lay out on that, please? What do you mean by that? I still have no `%` sign in the `<p>`?!?

Comment: @BharathRallapalli Yeah, of course it works. ;) Thank you. See my edited answer, perhaps it is about the `xhr` object?

Answer (score 0):

use $('.bartext').html(percentComplete + "%");

Are you shure, that percentComplete  has a value
?

Comment: So? If `$('.bartext')` is a jQuery Array collection of DOM HTMLElements, they should all show the desired output of `textContent`.

Comment: Does not work. Was rational, but read this http://api.jquery.com/text/. In `forms` you can use this to get text, but it is usually used to set text. ;)

Comment: `percentComplete` has a value, as you can see in the `console.log`, but there should still be a `%` in the `<p>`. ;)

Comment: do you use it together with another framework like [AngularJS]?

Comment: @Lisa-Berlin No, simply jQuery. But why is that of relevance? Because of the `$`? Thanks for staying up. ;)